# OpenLayers has wrong overlay positioning while zooming out

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

I'm quite new to OpenLayers. Right now I'm using it with OSM for a project and I'm facing what seems an issue to me: when I set an Overlay while zoomed in to max resolution, then, when I zoom out, the marker looks like it have moved to a different location. If I zoom in again everything is correct.

I this a bug in OpenLayers?

I'm using projection EPSG:3857 all the time and the marker positioning is set to "bottom-center".

Here is an image of the issue:
[image: map]
From left to right:
- 1. what I set
- 2. what I see when zooming out
- 3. What should be

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use a `ol.layer.Vector` instead of an `ol.Overlay` to display markers, especially if you have many.

Second, take a look at [this Icon example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html) in OpenLayers.  The marker always **points** to the correct location.  That is: because its center is not the location.

Look at the style definition:

```
  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/examples/data/icon.png'
    }))
  });
```

The `anchor` property defines where the image should **points**, by default it is the center of the image.  See the [ol.style.Icon API doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html).

For your case, it would seem that the center of the image points to the location, where you would have wanted to bottom tip to do that.  Try the `ol.layer.Vector` with icon style definition, instead.

Comment: There should be a bug in OpenLayers. It has a similar behaviour using Vectors. If Y offset for the icon seems fine, but not X offset. It seems that setting anchorXUnits to "pixels" causes the very same problems. Settings anchorXUnits to fraction seems to work fine but there is a tiny offset.
I'll try to open a bug in their website

Comment: Only 3 years later, but how do you set a bunch of images on the map?  Just run through a loop or is there a setAll() type of call?  Thanks.

Comment: @JustAspMe I suggest you open a new thread about your question in which you describe more what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried to do so far.